# 'angular' is not defined (scripts not linking together)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, pug, mean-stack

I'm trying to get my first real MEAN stack to work so this might be a rookie mistake.

Why are the angular module in app.js and the functions in controllers.js remaining undefined  ('Angular' is not defined, 'PollListCtrl' is not defined, etc.)

Many thanks in advance!

here is the index.jade

```
extends layout

doctype html

html(lang='en', ng-app='polls')
block content
    p Welcome to #{title}
    head
        meta(charset='utf-8')
        meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no')
        title= title
        script(src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular.js')
        script(src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular-resource.js')
        script(src='/public/js/controllers.js')
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.1/css/bootstrap.css')
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
        script(src='/public/js/services.js')
        script(src='/public/js/app.js')
    body(ng-controller='PollListCtrl')
        nav.navbar.navbar-inverse.navbar-fixed-top(role='navigation')
            div.navbar-header
                a.navbar-brand(href='#/poll')= title
            div.container
                div(ng-view)
```

and the first lines of controller.js

```
    function PollListCtrl($scope, Poll) {
      $scope.polls = Poll.query();
    }
```

...and app.js

```
angular.module('polls', ['pollServices']).config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.when('/polls', { templateUrl: 'partials/list.html', controller: 
PollListCtrl }).when('/poll/:pollId', { templateUrl: 'partials/item.html', controller: 
PollItemCtrl }). when('/new', { templateUrl: 'partials/new.html', controller: 
PollNewCtrl }).otherwise({ redirectTo: '/polls' });
}]);
```

Comment: Nothing too crazy is jumping out at me, but I have limited experience with jade. I would include app.js before the services/controllers/etc, but I don't think that's a breaking issue (I could be wrong). Are you sure the angular.js file is being successfully loaded? Check the network tab of the dev console, and if it's there, try loading just the angular file and looking at window.angular to see if that exists.

Comment: That's indeed not the issue since he's getting an Angular not defined error which is loaded before his application. However, the order of loading the applicationassets does matter, the application declaration (app.js) has got to be loaded before any controllers, directives, services etc because they need to be hooked onto the application instance. First declare angular.module('myApp', []); then after that you can declare angular.module('myApp').controller('myController', []); The other way around obviously wont work. I would as @dvlsg said check your networkwindow to see if angular is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues going on here that you need to clean up.

- First, you need to reference your app.js after angular.js but before any other modules which might use it.
- Secondly, the signature of your app is not set up correctly.  you need to assign `angular.module` 
  to a variable, i.e.: `var polls = angular.module('polls', ...`.
- Your Controller signature is not correct either.  In order for the controller to access the resources of your app, it needs to be defined on your app module. `polls.controller('pollListCtrl', [$scope, function($scope) { ...`

also note, controller names generally do not begin with a capital.

Hopefully that gets you a bit more established, but I would highly recommend reading the [Angular.js Tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial), so that you have a bit better feel for the angular way of doing things.

**Edit**

As was pointed out, as an alternative, you could skip assigning your application to a variable, and then fully reference the application when hooking up the controllers:

```
angular.module('polls').controller('pollListCtrl', [$scope, function($scope){
...
```

Most examples will show the first form, but many argue that the more explicit design is a better practice.

Comment: Declaring a controller by using .Controller won't work, .controller will. Also, there is absolutely no need to assign the application instance to a variable, it's even discouraged because of scopepolution. Instanciating an application like angular.module('myApp') and afterwards hooking up your  controllers, directives and such like: angular.module('myApp').controller('myController') is perfectly fine and even better than declaring everything in scope.